# Print out everything inside array in php

Tags: php

can anyone explain why I can't see what's inside the array? I think it supposed to be able to have multiple numbers (subscriptions) so maybe that's why I'm having trouble? Here's the code.

```
 $num = $_SESSION['subscription_ids'];
 if(is_array($num))
  {
print_r($num);
  }
    else
  {
echo "not an array";
   }

//Thanks DonnieM, yet It's spliting out "Array ( ) " no joke.
```

What is going on?

Comment: What *do* you get instead? `print_r` ought to output *something*.

Comment: what is the output from var_dump($_SESSION['subscription_ids']);

Comment: for print_r it has array() and var dump states NULL

Comment: OK, `Array ( )` means the array is empty. `NULL` is suspicious. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` on top of your code...

Comment: you have an empty array, how are you populating  $_SESSION['subscription_ids'] ?

Comment: Sorry deceze, actually, it gave out "array(0)" not NULL.

Comment: So you have an empty array. What's the question? :)

Comment: I thought there was something inside that array lol, the is_array said there was since it gave a 1 instead of 0.... but I guess it's really empty then.

Comment: no is_array says its an array not that its not empty, for that use count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion apparently arises from the output of `1` for `is_array`.
`is_array` returns a **boolean** value (`true` or `false`). When *outputting* boolean values as text, `true` is represented as `1` and `false` as nothing (an empty string).

Therefore `1` just means *yes, this is an array*. It does not tell you how many elements there are in the array.

Comment: use count() to determine the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean ?

```
php > $a = array();
php > echo is_array($a);
1
php > print_r($a);
/* this is not empty, but an empty array */
Array
(
)
/* as long $a is initiate, it WILL NEVER return NULL */
php > var_dump($a);
array(0) {
}

/* but */
php > $a = array(null);
php > var_dump($a);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say off hand since I don't know what the value of $_SESSION['subscription_ids'] is. It looks to me that you are using the is_array function incorrectly. It returns a boolean value and you're just assigning it to a variable instead. Here is a link to the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

I would say structure your code like this:

```
$num = $_SESSION['subscription_ids'];
if(is_array($num))
{
    print_r($num);
}
else
{
    echo "not an array";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try foreach($num as $element){echo $element;}